# emacs shortcut to insert 4 space and remove 4 space

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Noob to emacs. I would like to create a shortcut in emacs to insert 4 space from current cursor position and remove 4 white spaces from current cursor position. 
May be map it to C > and C <
Can somebody help me with this ?

Thanks in advance

zer0 0ne

Comment: Is this for code indentation? Any particular language? Emacs users usually use automated indentation, and configure it to suit, so possibly you don't need to do this.

Comment: @phils Yes it is for code indentation. I have set c-mode with linux style. The tab works only on beginning of line and does not work when I try to align assignments on tab boundaries :( 

P.S. I have tried align to align code blocks but the alignment is ugly to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can replicate any key as many times as you want by adding a numeric prefix:

```
ESC <number> <key>
```

so you can do:

```
 ESC 4 SPACE
```

or
      ESC 4 BACKSPACE

if you want to make it permanent, define a macro for each and  name it, and then assign it to a keystroke. see this for more details:

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros

or you make a function, but for this purpose is an overkill, I feel.

-dmg

---

Comment: `C-u <number> <key>` also works, if you want to keep your hands closer to the home row.

Comment: Or `C-<number> <key>` or `M-<number> <key>`, but my impression is that Zero One will be doing this too frequently to want to supply an argument each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily map a key or keys to insert or delete spaces if you really want to, but that's not the Emacs Way.  Customize c-mode to indent the way you want it to, and then you'll never have to manually tweak indentation again (and when you are looking at someone else's code and want to reindent it the way you like you just have to mark the whole buffer and type `M-x indent-region`--oh, the power!).

[Emacs manual on customizing C mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Customizing-Indentation)

[Emacs Wiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC)

Comment: Won't affect `c-mode` obviously, but keep in mind that [some](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html) languages [are](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) whitespace sensitive, so `indent-region` on the entire buffer isn't always the best idea.

Comment: @Inaimathi: Good point.  I don't know anything about Haskell, but in python-mode `indent-region` isn't going to do any good and may do harm, since for any given line there may be multiple possible syntactically and semantically correct indentation points.